# I dont want my navbar covering the top of my background image

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm using bootstrap classes and python flask.
I have a navbar with these classes:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
```

And this is my fixed background image

```
<div class="home-wrap">
    <div class="home-inner" style="background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, .3), rgba(0, 0, 0, .3)),  url('static/img/Produkte/all.JPG');">
    
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried:

```
.home-inner {
position: relative;
top: 60px;
}
```

This worked but when i would resize the screen there would be a gap.

How can I make it so the navbar doesn't cover the top of my background image and make it responsive?

Comment: Instead of positioning, try adding some `padding-top` to `.home-inner`.

Comment: can you provide a code pen or a fiddle so we can see what you did?

Comment: You should use some Javascript to find the actual height of the div save that into a variable and add it to the `home-inner` top property. That should work.

Comment: I don't know what a code pen or fiddle is, I would love to provide it.

Comment: simply write the same code that you wrote and think is the problem in you'r project here: https://jsfiddle.net/ and share the link here

Answer (score 0):

Without any code it's a bit hard to imagine what is wrong.

You might want to try removing the `fixed-top` class from the `navbar` (see bellow)

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
```

The fixed-top class is a default class use by Bootstrap to change the container position to `position:fixed;top:0` ([see bootstrap doc here](https://v5.getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/helpers/position/#fixed-top))

**EDIT:** If you want you navbar to still follow the scroll path without being over your image on first load you can replace the `fixed-top` class by the `sticky-top` class on the navbar ([see doc here](https://v5.getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/helpers/position/#sticky-top)).

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark sticky-top">
```

**Depending on your Bootstrap version, this might not work.** If i rmbr correctly, `sticky-top` was implemented in Bootstrap > 4.x (Documentation i'm linking is for Bootstrap >= 5.x, try looking at the documentation your website is using)

Comment: No problem, don't hesitate to thumbs up the answer if it helps you